# spin_lock_irqsave

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am facing odd problem with spin_lock_irqsave on a uni processor machine. 
I have a piece of critical code/function named with rx_process which is shared by two functions rx_timeout and rx_callback. This is located under a Linux kernel driver omap-serial.c

```
rx_process ( uartNum)
{
//critical section
}

rx_timeout (uartNum)//this is called from softIrq context upon timer expiry
{ 
   rx_process (uartNum);
}
rx_callback(uartNum)//this is called when interrupt handler registers upon interrupt and when 4k buf is full in rx_process function which invokes start_rx_dma which results in this call back function.
{
   rx_process (uartNum);
}
```

I found that the race condition was happening between these two functions, hence I decided to introduce spin_lock_irqsave in the rx_process at the beginning of the function and at the end of the function, but it still result in race condition and from time to time, I observe data loss and kernel panic.

```
rx_process ( uartNum)
{ spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
 //critical section
 spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
}
rx_timeout (uartNum)//this is called from softIrq context upon timer expiry
{ 
  rx_process (uartNum);
}
rx_callback(uartNum)//this is called when interrupt handler registers upon interrupt and when 4k buf is full in rx_process function which invokes start_rx_dma which results in this call back function
{
 rx_process (uartNum);
}
```

Now, I moved spin_lock_irqsave to rx_timeout as well as to rx_callback function and I don't see race condition.

```
 rx_process ( uartNum)
    { 
     //critical section
     spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
    }
    rx_timeout (uartNum)//this is called from softIrq context upon timer expiry
    { 
      spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
      rx_process (uartNum);
      spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
    }
    rx_callback(uartNum)//this is called when interrupt handler registers upon interrupt and when 4k buf is full in rx_process function which invokes start_rx_dma which results in this call back function
    {
     spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
     rx_process (uartNum);
     spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain the reason why the spin_lock_irqsave used inside the rx_process is failing and not preventing race conditions?

Comment: There's probably some code that accesses the same data structures from another context, not covered by the lock. It's possible that both case are not safe, but unsafe code tends to be chaotic, and meaningless changes make the problems happen or not.